# Is there an option in bigquery to bulk select data similar to Oracle bulk select

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It will be interesting to know how to bulk select data in bigquery. For example.

```
                SELECT catalog_name as project_name
                    , schema_name as dataset_name
                    , option_name
                    , option_type
                    , option_value
                    , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as _insert_timestamp
                FROM `{}`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA_OPTIONS
```

in this query instead of passing project by project in a loop. Is it possible to bulk select data for all projects in an array. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't. You have to write a procedure that iterate over the project and use execute immediate on each generated query thanks to the project in the iteration. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/procedures

Comment: Thanks for confirming we can't bulk select.